# JQUERY: How do I select an option by value?

Tags: jquery

```
<tfoot>
    <select>
        <option value="222"></option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
        <option value="zaza">zaza</option>
    </select>
</tfoot>
```

I tried that:

```
$('tfoot select').val('zaza');
```

```js
$("tfoot select").val("zaza")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tfoot>
    <select>
        <option value="222"></option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
        <option value="zaza">zaza</option>
    </select>
</tfoot>
```

Any idea ? 
Select = make it selected = trigger the change event

Comment: Note that selecting an option from Javascript won't automatically trigger a `change` event. You need to do that explicitly after you set the value.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
$('option[value="222"]')
```

In general,

`$("tag[attr=value]")` will search a `tag` with attributte `attr` and value `value`

To select it,

```
$('option[value="222"]').prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#clientList").children('[value="zaza"]').attr('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tfoot>
    <select id="clientList">
        <option value="222">222</option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
        <option value="zaza">zaza</option>
    </select>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? I "select" the value on `$(document).ready`

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <select>
        <option value="222">222</option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
        <option value="zaza">zaza</option>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("tfoot select").val("zaza");
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0skmm4pp/

By the way the `<tfoot>` tag is wrong, you are missing the `<tr>` tag and `<td>` tag. Or you can use `rupps` answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the option using the property [selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp):

```
var selectedIndex = $('select').prop('selectedIndex');
var option= $('select').find('option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')');
```

Or just targeting it via index:

```
var option= $('select').find('option:eq(0)');
```

Or target it directly:

```
var option = $('option[value="zaza"]');
```

To select any of the above references use:

```
option.attr('selected', true);
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var option = $('option[value="zaza"]');
  option.attr('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tfoot>
    <select>
        <option value="222" selected>selected</option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
        <option value="zaza">zaza</option>
    </select>
</tfoot>

<button>Change</button>
```

Comment: ok: that finds the element, but does not select it visually (or trigger the change event)

Comment: Yes. Change the attribute 'selected' to true. I have it in my answer.

Comment: I've added a snippet for you to see that it does select it visually.